# What UML diagrams to use for data flow between instances?

Tags: uml

For example, the program has a TxtFile class with:
   a string attribute called data.
   a read method that takes filename as argument. it reads the file with filename and put the content into the data attribute.
   a write method that takes filename as argument. it write the data attribute's content to the file with the filename.
   an append method that takes a string as argument. it append the string to the data attribute.

The main function of the program uses two instances of the TxtFile (called A and B) to read two different files. Then append data of B to A. Then write A to a new txt file.

What UML diagram(s) should I use to describe the data flow between the instances in the main function?

I don't know UML. Here is what I would draw to describe what happened in the main function after doing an image search on UML (yea...)

```
(filename A) ---> [TxtFile instance 1]
                  [data              ] 
                  [append            ] <---+
(filename C) -->  [write             ]     |
                                           |
(filename B) ---> [TxtFile instance 2      |
                   data              ] ----+
```

Comment: i suspect this is wrong on so many levels. Kind of a miracle that I don't get a gazillion down votes yet. Oh wait. no one read this question anyway.

Comment: There should be a label called "wrong, do not consume" on the bottle. A skull poison label takes too much effort.

Comment: Forget about this. this should be several diagrams: 1. a flow chart with steps like read txt file A with txtFile class. 2. a diagram that documents the classes.

Comment: Tough to ask under UML if you confess you don't know UML. You should get yourself a book and work through it first. This is not a tutorial place.

Comment: What is the point of your comments? Click on 'edit' & edit your question.

Comment: I would try [UML Sequence Diagram](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/sequence-diagrams-examples.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a diagram called "information flow" in UML 2.5, maybe it is a solution for your question.

[Exemple from the norm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v5zwj.jpg)

Norm "says" : "The InformationFlows package supports exchange of information between system entities at high levels of abstraction.
InformationFlows may be useful during top-down model development, representing aspects of models not yet fully
specified, and for recording less detailed, heuristic representations of more complex model areas. In these ways,
InformationFlows can help to clarify and document overall understanding of the intent of large or complicated models."